# My Android Studio project files all deleted after I clicked on VCS > Shelve Changes, can I recover them?

Tags: android, android-studio

I just finished my Android app project and I wanted to upload it on Git with my Android Studio, but I have never used Git before.

The last thing I remember clicking was 'Shelve Changes', and all my project files just deleted. They are all completely gone, and I am just looking at a blank screen.

What do I do to recover my project files?

Answer (score 1):

The files are not deleted, they are moved to a temp area which managed by Android studio, you can find them here:

[image]

Under the Shelf tab, there is a list of all your `Shelve Changes`, right click on it and choose `Unshelve...` then you can get your files back.